# c# multi - point selection on an image

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

I'm designing interface with visual c# for my image processing project. I need point selection on an image and classification these points for using in my image processing code at vhdl.

Original image will stay at a picturebox and I will use selected image in another picturebox.

How I can select points on an image?

Comment: Please don't cross post: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144094/c-multi-point-selection-on-an-image

Comment: What do you mean with "*select points*"? Get color under mouse? What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get pixel color and coord when mouse is down over picturebox, you could use

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pb.Image;
    Color col = bmp.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
    // Do what you please with pixel coord and color
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I need to pixel coord. I will select twelve points on an grayscale image. I will create array with them and classify as black and white and gray.